# How might a local float variable become corrupted in Java (Android 8.0.0)?

Tags: java, local-variables, corruption

UPDATED with significant new info (see bottom)

EDITED with better logging code

I'm tracking down some graphical corruption in our app, and have traced it to this function (which I have liberally sprinkled with logging):

```
public final int p_PostDraw(){
    bb_std_lang.print("Dissolve encountered.");
    float t_d=c_GColour.m_dissolve;
    bb_std_lang.print("Cached dissolve value locally: "+c_GColour.m_dissolve+ " " + t_d);
    c_GColour.m_dissolve=c_Gel.m_colstack.p_Top().m_a;
    bb_std_lang.print("Updated dissolve value: " + c_GColour.m_dissolve);
    c_Gel.m_colstack.p_Top().m_a=1.0f;
    bb_std_lang.print("Monitoring t_d="+t_d);
    super.p_PostDraw();
    bb_std_lang.print("Monitoring t_d="+t_d);
    c_GColour.m_dissolve=t_d;
    bb_std_lang.print("Dissolve post restore " + c_GColour.m_dissolve);
    return 0;
}
```

Most of the time this works as expected, but at a certain point in the game, this is logged:

```
09-30 14:40:59.086 10545-11101/? I/[Monkey]: Dissolve encountered.
09-30 14:40:59.086 10545-11101/? I/[Monkey]: Cached dissolve value locally: 1.0 1.0
09-30 14:40:59.086 10545-11101/? I/[Monkey]: Updated dissolve value: 0.1
09-30 14:40:59.086 10545-11101/? I/[Monkey]: Monitoring t_d=1.0
09-30 14:40:59.087 10545-11101/? I/[Monkey]: Monitoring t_d=-1.6314132E-19
09-30 14:40:59.087 10545-11101/? I/[Monkey]: Dissolve post restore -1.6314132E-19
```

To break that down for you: a static value **m_dissolve** is copied into a local variable **t_d**, and has the value 1.0f. The static value is then modified to 0.1f and used in the rendering of child objects. When this is complete, the local variable **t_d** is logged again prior to being used to reinstate the static value, but has mysteriously become -1.6314132E-19 in the meantime (this value seems unpredictably different each time).

I'm not aware of any way a local Java variable could be corrupted in this way.

**UPDATE:**

As a test I made t_d a member variable of the class containing the code listing above (rather than a local variable), and its value was no longer corrupted.

As a further test I then added some local float variables (m_e to m_j) that were used for nothing except printing out before and after super.p_PostDraw(). This is what happened:

```
09-30 15:20:51.219 28384-28877/? I/[Monkey]: M_E ETC BEFORE: 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
09-30 15:20:51.220 28384-28877/? I/[Monkey]: M_E ETC AFTER: 6.7E-44 6.7E-44 6.7E-44 6.7E-44 6.7E-44 6.7E-44
```

I then removed all filters from the logcat and found this lurking between those two lines:

```
09-30 15:20:51.219 28384-28877/? I/[Monkey]: M_E ETC BEFORE: 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
09-30 15:20:51.220 28384-28877/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_IffLT.p_Update4(app.hidden.name.c_Gel) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:20:51.220 28384-28877/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_Delay.p_Pump2(app.hidden.name.c_Gel) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:20:51.220 28384-28877/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_SetUniform_4F.p_Update4(app.hidden.name.c_Gel) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:20:51.220 28384-28877/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_EX_VarString.p_Set7(app.hidden.name.c_Expression) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:20:51.220 28384-28877/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing java.lang.String app.hidden.name.c_EX_Format.p_AsString() due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:20:51.220 28384-28877/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_IffNotEqual.p_Update4(app.hidden.name.c_Gel) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:20:51.220 28384-28877/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_PinVP.p_Update4(app.hidden.name.c_Gel) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:20:51.220 28384-28877/? I/[Monkey]: M_E ETC AFTER: 6.7E-44 6.7E-44 6.7E-44 6.7E-44 6.7E-44 6.7E-44
```

**UPDATE:**

I tweaked the code above to set the local variables to different values rather than all being 1.0f, and this happened:

```
09-30 15:56:37.686 1815-2373/? I/[Monkey]: M_E BEFORE: 2.0 1.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 1.0
09-30 15:56:37.687 1815-2373/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_IffLT.p_Update4(app.hidden.name.c_Gel) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:56:37.687 1815-2373/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_Delay.p_Pump2(app.hidden.name.c_Gel) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:56:37.687 1815-2373/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_SetUniform_4F.p_Update4(app.hidden.name.c_Gel) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:56:37.687 1815-2373/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_EX_VarString.p_Set7(app.hidden.name.c_Expression) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:56:37.688 1815-2373/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing java.lang.String app.hidden.name.c_EX_Format.p_AsString() due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:56:37.688 1815-2373/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_IffNotEqual.p_Update4(app.hidden.name.c_Gel) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:56:37.688 1815-2373/? I/zygote64: Deoptimizing int app.hidden.name.c_PinVP.p_Update4(app.hidden.name.c_Gel) due to JIT inline cache
09-30 15:56:37.688 1815-2373/? I/[Monkey]: M_E AFTER: 2.0 -5.6063644E-30 3.0 4.0 5.0 -5.6063644E-30
```

In other words, only the local variable set to 1.0f was corrupted. Not the first one declared or anything, JUST the one set to 1.0f. I then tried setting all the local variables to different numbers OTHER than 1.0f and **no corruption occurred**.

Surely there must be some kind of prize for the most obscure bug ever? That a local variable will get corrupted if the ART deoptimises functions, but only if that local variable has the value 1.0?

Comment: What environment is this operating in? Is there JNI/JNA code involved?

Comment: Perhaps `t_d` was `6.7E-44`all along: it's not printed before `pre restore`.

Comment: Sorry, I did check that but didn't include it in the OP. Will amend.

Comment: Okay, I've amended the OP so that t_d is monitored throughout, and you can see it gets corrupted somewhere inside super.p_PostDraw()

Comment: We are also having this bug now. It was very difficult to find the issue, thank you for the question here. Do you have any update for the issue @Peeling ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really weird issue and seems that it is bug in ART/JIT.
I can see at least 3 different developer stories with same problem. I think there could be a lot more of them but this bug is really difficult to reproduce.

I faced this issue during development of the game using LibGDX framework. UI in this framework is created with a lot of complex calculations and floats are intensively used there. In my case UI components received wrong coordinates, so layout was completely broken.

Weird thing that you can't reproduce this issue with DEBUG apk, only with RELEASE apk. Changing value of manifest `android:debuggable=true` also will not work. So debugging is really painfull, you need to monitor logcat and verify values of float variables.

There is an issue which was created by @Peeling, so if you have related problem please ask android devs to fix it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141825192

#### Workaround

I forced compiler to perform "Deoptimization" of the methods related to UI before I actually need them. I created mock "Table" component, filled it with other mock components  (creating layout similar to real one) and called the methods which I was able to see in the logs (when Deoptimization was happening). I'm making this operation every time on application start and issue seems to be "fixed" for me - "Deoptimization" never happens after this point and layout is always correct after this.

I hope it will help someone who also spent a lot of time on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I‘ve also had this problem in my released game with LibGDX, just like tscissors.

After many months debugging, now I am sure that the problems I‘ve had were related to destroyed float-variables, like described in this post.

For me an easy workaround helped: In the `AndroidManifest.xml` setting the attribute `android:vmSafeMode` to  `true` eliminated the bug successfully, since it disables the JIT optimizations.

See android description:

`android:vmSafeMode`

> Indicates whether the app would like the virtual machine (VM) to operate in safe mode. The default value is "false".
>   This attribute was added in API level 8 where a value of "true" disabled the Dalvik just-in-time (JIT) compiler.
>
> This attribute was adapted in API level 22 where a value of "true" disabled the ART ahead-of-time (AOT) compiler.

Comment: This can affect application performance. Have you noticed any changes in performance after adding this value? I also tried this option, but after reading some warnings and due to the lack of official documentation, I decided to look for another solution.

Comment: Yes, the performance aspect is an important point and finally it‘s a tradeoff between risking layout bugs (or potentially other weird behaviours) and performance problems.
In my case, only the time while my AIs are calculating is increased noticeably and the rendering is still good nearly 60 FPS. I can sleep much better with the little worse calculating time of the AIs than with the fear that the layouts are broken arbitrarily. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not aware of any way a local Java variable could be corrupted in this way.

It could happen if some native code somewhere is trampling the stack frame that contains the `t_d` variable.

It could also happen if there is a race condition or memory hazard in this section:

```
   float t_d=c_GColour.m_dissolve;
   bb_std_lang.print("Dissolve pre stack: " + c_GColour.m_dissolve);
```

If you look carefully, you are not actually printing `t_d`.  What you are doing is printing the (apparent) value of `c_GColour.m_dissolve` ... *after* it has been assigned to `t_d`.  It might have changed.

(Note that you are accessing a bare variable `m_dissolve`, apparently without any synchronization.  There is a potential race condition here even if `m_disolve` is declared as `volatile`.)

Comment: Thanks - I did have a version where I printed t_d but didn't include that in the OP. Am amending now. Also only one thread ever accesses m_dissolve.

Comment: OK, so my money is now on a problem with native code or maybe incorrect use of `Unsafe`.

Comment: I threw together some more tests and removed all filters from logcat. Does that change where your money would go?

Comment: Yea.  It could be a hardware error or a compiler bug.  But you *didn't mention* that this was Android rather than Java ... and that could make a difference too.

Comment: *smack forehead* Thanks; I went through about five different titles for this and managed to lose 'Android' on the one I settled for.